# angular2 - ROUTER_PROVIDERS is not defined

Tags: angular, router

I have this code in my **system.config.js** when it comes to importing angular2's old router (the deprecated one).

```
'@angular/router-deprecated': 'npmcdn:@angular/router-deprecated@'+angularVersion,
```

I'm getting this error:

```
system.src.js:43 Uncaught (in promise) Error: ROUTER_PROVIDERS is not defined(…)
```

This is the plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OKQFwSK62hk4pJlrL1Pn?p=preview)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plunker has several problems.

#### At `app/index.ts`:

- Add the imports:

  ```
  import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
  import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
  import { provide } from '@angular/core';
  ```
- Not mandatory, but you should remove the `.ts` extension:

  ```
  import { App } from './app2.ts';
  ```

  Should really be:

  ```
  import { App } from './app2';
  ```

#### At `app/home.ts`

- Add the path to the `templateUrl`:

  ```
  templateUrl: './home.html'
  ```

  Becomes:

  ```
  templateUrl: './app/home.html'
  ```

#### At `app/add_developer.ts`

- Also add the path to the `templateUrl`:

  ```
  templateUrl: './add_developer.html'
  ```

  Becomes:

  ```
  templateUrl: './app/add_developer.html'
  ```

#### General: Update `*ngFor` notation

- Consider updating the `*ngFor` notation to the latest. You are using it in several places. Use `let` instead of `#`. For instance, at `app/home.html`:

  ```
  <tr *ngFor="#dev of getDevelopers()">
  ```

  Should be

  ```
  <tr *ngFor="let dev of getDevelopers()">
  ```

[Click here for your **updated plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/s1MsFOslpoQoNBlS3v8S?p=preview) (including the `*ngFor` changes).

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in **index.ts**

```
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
```

And add `providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]` in you **app2.ts** file.